# Can I use user-based recommendation on hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I'm reading 'Mahout in action',From this book, It has come to my attention that I can set a item-based recommendations.So I want to know is there anybody have set a user-based recommendation.
And as I know FileDataModel supports update files,this is used on sigle PC. How about on hadoop?

Comment: Not sure if off topic...

Comment: You should accept more answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is no user-based recommender algorithm available on Hadoop. It would be possible to write. In general I would steer you towards item-item similarity-based approaches at that scale. No there is no notion of update files in Hadoop as it's not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,does the item-item similarity-based approaches you said are actually item-based approaches.And if I get some new data,Must I calculate all of them again?

Comment: You can always use older item-item similarity values if you feel they're probably still about valid. It's up to you when to recompute them.

Comment: I want to ask an other question.Did mahout have implemented some algorithms on recommender except the algorithms in your book?

Comment: Probably better asked on the mailing list, or in the Mahout in Action forums, but, yes there have been more implementations. See for example the alternating-least-squares implementations.

Comment: Could you clarify how one would create this Hadoop implementation. I.e. do you utilize some existing Mahout's user-based recommender components to achieve this, or do you need to come up and write the entire algorithm from scratch as a MapReduce job on your own? Also preferably the scoring should be combinable with the item-based recommender job, just like the non-hadoop counterpart.